# VB.Net ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview, dataset

I am trying to use a ListView to display records from a dataset. In these records, I have 4 columns: EmployeeID, EmployeeName, CustomerID, and CustomerName. It is possible for both the Employee and Customer to be listed multiple times, but with different combinations.

For instance, if we have Employees 1, 2, 3 and Customers A, B, C we could have:
(1A)
(1B)
(1C)
(2A)
(2B)
etc.

What's going on with mine is I add say (1A) to the listView and then when it tries to add (1B) I get an error saying that it cannot add the same item.

Here is my code so far:

```
With list
     .Clear()
     .Columns.Add("Employee ID")
     .Columns.Add("Employee Name")
     .Columns.Add("Customer ID")
     .Columns.Add("Customer Name")
     For Each row As UpFromCostExceptions.dtExceptionsRow In _dsExceptions.dtExceptions
         Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = .Items.Add(row.EmpID.ToString)
         lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.EmployeeName)
         lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.CustomerID)
         lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.CustomerName)
     Next
     .Refresh()
End With
```

Anyone see what is going on? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't see where you are using data from combined fields. If CustomerID is numeric, you need to include .ToString() as you did with EmpID.

Comment: I'm not using combined data in a single field. But I have 2 items for the listView. Both items have the same value for EmpID but different values for CustomerID. When I try to add the second item, it get an error because it cannot add the same EmpID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that if I go through and create the item and add the subitems before adding the ListViewItem into the ListView I can have duplicate values. Here is the code that I used:

```
With listExceptions
            .Clear()
            .Columns.Add("Employee ID")
            .Columns.Add("Employee Name")
            .Columns.Add("Customer ID")
            .Columns.Add("Customer Name")
            For Each row As UpFromCostExceptions.dtExceptionsRow In _dsExceptions.dtExceptions
                Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem(row.EmpID.ToString)
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.EmployeeName)
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.CustomerID)
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(row.CustomerName)
                listExceptions.Items.Add(lvItem)
            Next
            .Refresh()
        End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I have simple class with two fields, identifier,Title, I populated list in a function like this way.

```
'lstv = is the actual ListView Control
Dim i As Integer
Dim listitem As New ListViewItem
If lstv.Items.Count > 0 Then
    lstv.Items.Clear()
End If
For i = 0 To PropertyList.Count - 1
    listitem = New ListViewItem(PropertyList(i).Idefntifier)
    listitem.SubItems.Add(PropertyList(i).Title)        
    lstv.Items.Add(listitem)
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making row.EmpID.ToString() a unique and see if it still throws an exception.

```
  Dim lvItem As ListViewItem = .Items.Add(row.EmpID.ToString)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The list needs to be able to accept duplicates in a way but as long as the entire row does not match another row. A single EmployeeID should be able to appear multiple times in the list as long as the CustomerIDs are different. If you are referring to something else, please clarify.

Comment: Yes I understand, I was not clear your inital string that you enter into Items.Add needs to be unique anything in the subitems does not because the items are stored in a hash